# Table textwrapping

Tags: tables, boxes

I'm trying to obtain a table like this, but the output I had doesn't satisfy me. Do you know how can I change this code?

This is the table I'm trying to get:

[image]

This is the table that I obtain:

[image]

You can see that at the beginning, for example, "No metabolic effects" and "Infection (not higher than in background population" are not aligned to "Copper".

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=35mm, right=25mm, top=30mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}   


\begin{table}[htbp]
\footnotesize
\linespread{1}\selectfont
    \caption{Schematic overview of the different available contraceptive methods, and pro and cons for their use in women with diabetes}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{l l l l l}
                \toprule
                & \multirow{2}{2cm}{\textit{Methods}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Type 1 diabetes}}\\
                \cmidrule(l){3-4}
                & & \textit{Pro} & \textit{Con}\\
                \midrule
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{Barrier} & No metabolic effects & \parbox{5cm}{Compliance difficult\\Medium contraceptive efficacy}\\
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{IUD} & & \\
                & Copper & \parbox{5cm}{No metabolic effects\\Good compliance\\High contraceptive efficacy}& \parbox{5cm}{Infection (not higher than in background population)\\Bleeding disturbance}\\
                & Progestin containing & \parbox{5cm}{Decreased menstrual bleeding (Progestin-IUD)}& \\
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{Oral contraceptives} & \parbox{5cm}{Good bleeding control\\High contraceptive efficacy}& \parbox{5cm}{Risk of arterial thrombotic episode (higher than background population)\\Risk of venous thrombotic episode (as background population)\\Limited use in non-smoking women \textless{} 35 years with uncomplicated diabetes\\Increasing insulin resistance\\Decreasing glucose tolerance (not clinically relevant)}\\
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{Progestin-only pills} & \parbox{5cm}{No increased risk of vascular disease\\Medium-high contraceptive efficacy}& \parbox{5cm}{Non-optimal bleeding control\\Need to be taken at the same time everyday}\\
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{Long-acting hormonal methods} & High contraceptive efficacy & \parbox{5cm}{Non-optimal bleeding control\\Not been studied in women with diabetes}\\
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{Surgical sterilization} & & \\
                & Female & No metabolic effects & Irreversible\\
                & Male & High contraceptive efficacy & Need of an operation\\
                \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \label{tab:contraception_options}
\end{table}

\begin{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose this layout, for a better readability: I define two column typeswith contents in a  convenient `list` environment. Each line in a `Pro` or `Con` cell has to be introduced with `\item`. I also load the `caption` package for a better formatting, and I replace the `center` environment, which adds an unwanted vertical spacing, with `\centering`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=35mm, right=25mm, top=30mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption} \usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
    \newlist{tabenum}{itemize}{1}
    \setlist[tabenum]{label={}, labelsep=0pt, wide=0pt, nosep, leftmargin=1.5em, itemsep=2pt, before =\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\itemsep\relax}}%
    \newcolumntype{P}{>{\RaggedRight\tabenum\item[]}p{50mm}<{\endtabenum\vspace*{-2ex}}}%
    \newcolumntype{Q}{>{\RaggedRight\tabenum\item[]}X<{\endtabenum\vspace*{-2ex}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\footnotesize\centering\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\linespread{1}\captionsetup{format=hang}
    \caption{Schematic overview of the different available contraceptive methods,\\ and pro and cons for their use in women with diabetes}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}llPQ@{}}
                \toprule
                & \multirow{2}{2cm}{\textit{Methods}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Type 1 diabetes}}\\
                \cmidrule(l){3-4}
                & & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\itshape Pro} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\itshape Con}\\
                \midrule
\addlinespace
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{Barrier} & \item No metabolic effects & \item Compliance difficult \item Medium contraceptive efficacy\\
                \addlinespace
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{IUD} & & \\
                & Copper & \item No metabolic effects \item Good compliance \item High contraceptive efficacy %
                & \item Infection (not higher than in background population) \item Bleeding disturbance\\
                \addlinespace
             & Progestin containing & \item Decreased menstrual bleeding (Progestin-IUD)& \\
 \addlinespace
 \multicolumn{2}{l}{Oral contraceptives}%
  & \item Good bleeding control \item High contraceptive efficacy %
  & \item Risk of arterial thrombotic episode (higher than background population) \item Risk of venous thrombotic episode (as background population) \item Limited use in non-smoking women \textless{} 35 years with uncomplicated diabetes \item Increasing insulin resistance \item Decreasing glucose tolerance (not clinically relevant)\\
 \addlinespace
 \multicolumn{2}{l}{Progestin-only pills}%
  & \item No increased risk of vascular disease \item Medium-high contraceptive efficacy %
  & \item Non-optimal bleeding control \item Need to be taken at the same time everyday \\
 \addlinespace
 \multicolumn{2}{p{3.5cm}}{Long-acting hormonal methods}%
  & \item High contraceptive efficacy %
  & \item Non-optimal bleeding control \item Not been studied in women with diabetes\\
 \multicolumn{2}{l}{Surgical sterilization} & & \\
 &Female & \item No metabolic effects & \item Irreversible\\
 & Male & \item High contraceptive efficacy & \item Need of an operation\\
 \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab:contraception_options}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with your use of parboxes. You could ofcourse use add in the optional arguments to solve this also (`\parbox[pos][height][contentpos]{width}{text}`, where `pos` should be set to `t`, to top-align the content.). But this could be solved using a different columntype, namely `p{width}`, since you anyway are setting the same width in all of those parboxes. Then you don't need write the same over and over. Now you can use manual linebreaks, but you must use `\newline` since `\\` has a different meaning when in a tabular-environment (vertical mode).

I would also suggest to use the `Ragged2e`-package here, as it is better at dealing with linebreaks thand simply `\raggedright`, which looks better when in really small columns, in my opinion. Also, `tabularx` would be useful, to make the table fit into the text. I've now added in these options, but they're easy to remove. I also added some space, between a few selected lines, to make the information it a bit more clear, through the `booktabs`-command `\addlinespace`.

**Ouput**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=35mm, right=25mm, top=30mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}   


\begin{table}[htbp]
\footnotesize
\RaggedRight
\linespread{1}\selectfont
    \caption{Schematic overview of the different available contraceptive\newline methods, and pro and cons for their use in women with diabetes}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l l p{5cm} X}
                \toprule
                & \multirow{2}{2cm}{\textit{Methods}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Type 1 diabetes}}\\
                \cmidrule(l){3-4}
                & & \textit{Pro} & \textit{Con}\\
                \midrule
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{Barrier} & No metabolic effects & \parbox{5cm}{Compliance difficult\\Medium contraceptive efficacy}\\
                \addlinespace
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{IUD} & & \\
                & Copper & No metabolic effects\newline Good compliance\newline High contraceptive efficacy& Infection (not higher than in background population)\newline Bleeding disturbance\\
                \addlinespace
                & Progestin containing & Decreased menstrual bleeding (Progestin-IUD)& \\
                \addlinespace
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{Oral contraceptives} & Good bleeding control\newline High contraceptive efficacy& Risk of arterial thrombotic episode (higher than background population)\newline Risk of venous thrombotic episode (as background population)\newline Limited use in non-smoking women \textless{} 35 years with uncomplicated diabetes\newline Increasing insulin resistance\newline Decreasing glucose tolerance (not clinically relevant)\\
                \addlinespace
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{Progestin-only pills} & No increased risk of vascular disease\newline Medium-high contraceptive efficacy& Non-optimal bleeding control\newline Need to be taken at the same time everyday\\
                \addlinespace
                \multicolumn{2}{p{3.5cm}}{Long-acting hormonal methods} & High contraceptive efficacy & Non-optimal bleeding control\newline Not been studied in women with diabetes\\
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{Surgical sterilization} & & \\
                & Female & No metabolic effects & Irreversible\\
                & Male & High contraceptive efficacy & Need of an operation\\
                \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
    \label{tab:contraception_options}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```